# unity alternative to UNET for P2P server

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

Since UNET will be discontinued in a short time I have my doubt which alternative I can use, since photon does not help me to have a limited number of users since my game the idea is that each user creates a server and can join a friend (Will only be cooperative between 2 people), what do you recommend?

Comment: Your own network solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled around this issue for a little bit as well, I finally came to the conclusion that writing my own networking solution using sockets was the way to go. I ended up writing an "Instance" server that a unity client communicates with, and then a master server (Webapi/WCF) in which the instance talks to (The master is what talks to my database for player data).

I learned how to code the unity server portion from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7P8x2PkT71c

Best of luck.